# Repository pattern with Entity Frameworks 4

Tags: nhibernate, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern

I used to use NHibernate with repository interfaces.

What is the proper way to use this pattern with EF?
How can I implement this repository interface, for a `RepositoryBase<T>`?

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T GetById(object id);
    void Save(T entity);
    T[] GetAll();
    void Delete(T entity);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason all of the examples given expose the collections as IQueryable or IEnumerable.  EF4 has an interface for this very purpose - IObjectSet (or IDbSet if you're using the latest CTP).

Julie Lerman has a tremendous post on doing this, including creating a MockSet that implements IObjectSet, so you can do some disconnected unit testing

http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/agile-entity-framework-4-repository-part-6-mocks-amp-unit-tests/

Comment: Seem like IObjectSet is EF specific and therefore I would not like in a repository pattern. Point being that you dont want your Irepository having EF dependency

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a whole lot different than any other ORM.  Here's an example:  http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/01/20/using-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Entity Framework Repository & Unit of Work Template](http://efrepository.codeplex.com/). You have some details [here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/entity-framework-repository).

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches (most of them are quite similar and only differ slightly), so I would recommend doing some research and choosing which one suits you best.

With EF 4 it is possible to implement a generic repository by using `ObjectSet<T>`. Take a look at a few articles that might help:

http://devtalk.dk/2009/06/09/Entity+Framework+40+Beta+1+POCO+ObjectSet+Repository+And+UnitOfWork.aspx

http://www.forkcan.com/viewcode/166/Generic-Entity-Framework-40-Base-Repository

Answer (score 0):

You basically have your Repositories talk yo your object context. Only change I would make would be having your GetAll return an IEnumerable instead something like:

```
public class SomeObjectRepo : IRepository<SomeObject>
{
    SomeContext GetById(object id)
    {
        using(var context = new MyContext())
        {
            return context.SomeObjects.First(x=>x.id.Equals(id));
        }
    }

etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution: http://www.necronet.org/archive/2010/04/10/generic-repository-for-entity-framework.aspx

I like this because it doesn't couple instance of repository with specific instance of object context, so with some DI framework, I can have all my repositories be singletons.