# LINQ to SQL Generic Repository equivalent in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, repository, repository-pattern

I'm converting from LINQ to SQL to Entity Framework for my ORM and I'm updating my repositories. All of them are done except for the generic one. I can't seem to figure out how to convert my `Select` method from what it is now to one that works with EF. Here's the current code:

```
public T Select(int Id)
{
    MetaDataMember PrimaryKey = this.DataContext.Mapping.GetTable(typeof(T)).RowType.DataMembers.SingleOrDefault(
        d =>
            (d.IsPrimaryKey));
    ParameterExpression Param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");

    var Query = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(Param, PrimaryKey.Name), Expression.Constant(Id)), new ParameterExpression[] { Param });

    return this.DataContext.GetTable<T>().Single(Query);
}
```

I didn't write this, I copied it from some person's blog and it's worked for me so far. I really don't know what it does, vague idea, but I'm not capable of translating it to EF.

So, I've come here to ask for the assistance of you fine ladies or gentlemen. If possible, I'd love it if someone who knows EF can convert that statement. If there's alternative code to accomplish the same thing, I'm open to it.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383481/repository-pattern-with-entity-frameworks-4

Comment: How is that a duplicate? That question is very generic - how to implement repository with EF. This question is about porting L2SQL code over to EF.

Comment: @StefanP - I agree with @RPM1984 ; that is unrelated

Comment: My bad, I thought that T GetById(object id) is the same with your T Select(int Id)

Comment: Signature is similar yes, but implementation detail very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand that method correctly, it returns a single record for any type T, based on a primary key.

We also have a generic repository, but the interface looks like this:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
   void Add(T entity);
   void Remove(T entity);
   void Attach(T entity);
   IQueryable<T> Find();
}
```

And our generic repository implementation:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
   public IQueryable<T> Find()
   {
      return _ctx.GetEntitySet<T>(); // EF plularization/reflection smarts
   }
}
```

So to get the equivalent single record for a "Post":

```
var postId = 1;
IRepository<Post> repository = new GenericRepository<Post>(); // done by DI in reality
repository
   .Find()
   .SingleOrDefault(x => x.PostId == postId); // explicit predicate to grab record
```

That's a lot different to your original code - as the calling code is specifying what the primary key is (or a way to identity a unique record).

To be honest, trying to dynamically grab a unique record based on a constant primary key value is pretty crazy - **what if it's a composite key?** I can't see how that code would work.

Happy to see other answers, but i would keep it simple.

If you want the code to grab the entity set based on T, i can share that - but it's pretty simple.

If you want a method to grab a single record, let the calling code supply the predicate/key:

```
public T FindSingle(Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate)
{
   return _ctx.GetEntitySet<T>.SingleOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

Then if for example "Post" had a composite key of "PostName" and "PostType":

```
var singlePost = repository.FindSingle(post => post.PostName == "Foo" && post.PostType == "Question");
```

In your example, your repository is dictating your model, making each entity have a single column primary key.

Your repository should *aid* your model, not define it.

**EDIT - Code for `GetEntitySet<T>`, as requested**

```
public IObjectSet<T> GetEntitySet<T>() where T : class
{
   var entityName = _plularizer.Pluralize(typeof(T).Name);
   string entitySetName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", EntityContainerName, entityName);
   return CreateObjectSet<T>(entitySetName );
}
```

Pretty simple, and quite safe, because `_plularizer` is of type `System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationService`, which is the same module that EF uses to create default entity set names.

`EntityContainerName` is your container name for your entities.

Your `_plularizer` instance should be **static**, and kept thread-safe with a fully-locked singleton.

HTH.

Comment: Most keys aren't composite; the requirement itself isn't uncommon - consider things like route-centric Astoria: /orders/17 etc

Comment: Astoria? You mean OData, :) Very true though, just thought i'd mention the limitation, in case the OP wasnt aware. Also, would be difficult to port the above L2SQL code over to EF in a POCO scenario, where the PK isn't explicity defined on the class. In my situation, the Repositories get handed the OC, so it has no knowledge of the schema (EDMX). (which the above L2SQL repository does). Interested to see other answers though.

Comment: @RPM1984, I like your solution, but I have to ask, where does that `GetEntitySet<T>` come from? I assume that `_ctx` is the EF DataContext, so when I try to write the same code on my side I don't have an option for `GetEntitySet<T>`... I have `CreateObjectSet<T>`, is that the same thing? Is it a version difference?

Comment: @Alex - my bad, should have mentioned that. `GetEntitySet<T>` is a custom method i created to return an `ObjectSet<T>` based only on the name of T (reflection - name property), and pluralization. E.g if i have a `GenericRepository<Post>`, the code would return `ctx.Posts`. Will edit answer to include that code.

Comment: @RPM1984, I see. I understand what you mean about not having the repository dictate the model, but I've got a bit of an issue. I have the generic repository `Repository<T>`, but I also have a generic provider `Provider<T>` (for low-level objects) which relies on it and interacts with it via ids. I hate to bother you, but you would you happen to have a version that works directly with ids like in the original?

Comment: Sorry, i don't have code to do that. As i said, my `GenericRepository<T>` returns `IQueryable<T>`, not single records. Its up to my calling code (Service Layer / BLL) to fetch the unique record from that `IQueryable<T>`. If you want a direct EF version of your above L2SQL code - your basically going to have to use reflection. Sorry i can't be of more help.

Comment: @RPM1984, okay, I actually opted out of the generic provider and made specific providers for the "low-level" objects. I did go through all my repositories and converted them to the Expression example you had and I like it better, so thanks for that!

Comment: @Alex - glad to help. The `Expression` way isn't something i read in a book, it's basically a modified version of the specification pattern. Where the calling code supplies the filter, and has total flexibility on the result. Use with caution. :)

Comment: When i say "use with caution", i mean calling code could do `Find(x => x.Id > 0)` and basically return all records. What i do to counteract this is supply an parameter for maxRows, and do a `.Take(maxRows)` before returning the result. If they don't supply maxRows, default to a max take (e.g 50 rows).